# How can I get the new Google Talk on a Droid Incredible running 2.3.4?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, htc-droid-incredible, google-talk

I have the original Droid Incredible (hardware rev 0003) with the new Market. I just got the Gingerbread OTA but it didn't include the new Google Talk. I know I could manually install the new apk from some random website, but I'd rather get it the "official" way, if such exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a custom recovery, such as Clockwork Mod, I don't know of any way you can get the new talk.  If you have a custom recovery (which I don't think you do), you can install two zip files through ClockworkMod